# TeamCity synchronized Build Step or wait for a step to finish

Tags: teamcity

i am learning TeamCity, and trying to figure out how to have a Build Step (command line) triggered or run after all prior steps are completed? currently i have FxCop and Nunit with dotCover setup and would like to copy all temp files used in the build to another location at the end.

the problem i am having is that the last commandline step that does the xcopy runs before NUnit/dotCover is completed and temp files are produced.

any comments?

thanks,

Comment: Do you still have a problem with this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please comment your progress for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 2):

All your steps will be performed in turn, so somehow your previous steps seem to signal that they are ready before the output is written.

We use NAnt to make a "sleep" call for 10-15 seconds in some of our configurations, after a deploy for instance. Try that and see if it helps.

EDIT:
Our main target, with a sleep command in between:

```
<target name="deploy">
<call target="backupFiles" />
<call target="takeAppOffline" />
<call target="deleteOldFilesFromWebFolder" />
<call target="copyNewFilesToWebFolder" />
<sleep seconds="20" />
<call target="takeAppOnline" />
</target>
```

Comment: Can you share your sleep call?

Comment: Sure, have added to answer